# PHP Sort preg_match_all array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am working on a form process page that takes data that is pasted into a form and when submitted it takes the data and breaks it up into different matches.  I am having trouble figuring out the coding to sort the date based upon certain criteria.  Any help would be great.  Below is the code that I have so far for the foreach loop.  Also I am including what the output looks like with just this info.  I want to be able to sort by date and other variables.

**Here is the output of running the below code.**

694345
Approval
01/13-TR-OK
01/13/2015 03:32 pm
01/16/2015 05:00 pm
z-CHG GL Network Operations
PreApp

691098
Approval
01/05-TR-PEND *Not sure if reclaim attachment shou
01/05/2015 09:59 am
01/14/2015 05:00 pm
z-CHG GL Network Operations
PreApp

**Here is the code:**

```
<?php

 $lines = preg_split('/\n/', $_POST['changeQueue']);     // Split Pasted info into an array of lines


foreach ($lines as $line){
if (!preg_match('/^\d\d\d\d\d\d/', $line)){ 
    continue;                   // Skip this line if it doesn't start with a 6+ digit number
};

//Regex to capture the interesting parts from each line, should work for IE and Mozilla
$pattern = '/^(\d*)\s(\d*)\s(\S*)\s(\S*)\s(.*?)\s(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}\s\w\w)\s(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}\s\w\w)\s(.*?)\s(.*?)\s(\w*)\s?$/';
preg_match_all($pattern,$line,$matches);

//preg_match_all returns a multidimentional array of matches, [0][x] contains the original string(s) so we start with [1][0];
$ticketNumber = $matches[1][0];
#$taskSequence = $matches[2][0];
$taskType = $matches[3][0];
#$taskStatus = $matches[4][0];
$description = $matches[5][0];
$startDate = $matches[6][0];
$endDate = $matches[7][0];
#$asignee = $matches[8][0];
$team = $matches[9][0];
$normal = $matches[10][0];


// Print the variables just to verify that we caught all the info
print_r($ticketNumber);
echo "<br>";
print_r($taskType);
echo "<br>";
print_r($description);
echo "<br>";
print_r($startDate);
echo "<br>";
print_r($endDate);
echo "<br>";
print_r($team);
echo "<br>";
print_r($normal);
echo "<hr><br><br><br>";
};
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. With your usage, there's not really any point in using `preg_split()`. Instead, you could just as easily use `$lines = explode("\n", $_POST['changeQueue']);`. If you weren't using regular expressions for anything else, this would definitely be the way to go, so you don't have the overhead of firing up the regular expression engine. Since you are using regular expressions after this, it's not a big deal, but just an FYI.
2. Your first `preg_match()` pattern can be simplified: `'/^\d{6}/'`
3. I'm not sure you should be using `preg_match_all()` anyways. If you just use `preg_match()` and pass in the `$matches` parameter, it will fill `$matches` with the entire pattern that was matched at index 0, but then after that it will fill in each parenthesized sub-pattern that it matched. So you get the result you want with a one-dimensional array instead of an unnecessary multi-dimensional array.
4. Once you have a one-dimensional array in `$matches`, based on your code sample, it looks like your dates will be in `$matches[6]` and `$matches[7]`.

Now, it sounds like you want to sort `$lines` by the start or end date in each line. So, instead of looping through `$lines`, that's what you want to call [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) on. In the callback that you pass to `usort()`, split the line, get the values you want to sort by, and use those to compare the two lines. Then return a `-1`, `0`, or `1` from the callback to tell PHP how to sort those lines.

Here's an example of what this will look like (untested):

```
function parseLine($line) {
    $pattern = /* pattern to split line */;
    preg_match($pattern, $line, $matches);

    // drop the first element of the beginning of the array
    array_shift($matches);

    // we will give names to the values and return it as an associative array
    // this will help with accessing these values later on
    return array_combine(
        array(
            'ticketNumber',
            'taskSequence',
            'taskType',
            'taskStatus',
            'description',
            'startDate',
            'endDate',
            'asignee',
            'team',
            'normal',
        ),
        array_slice($matches, 0, 10)
    );
}

function compareLines($line1, $line2) {
    if ($line1['startDate'] < $line1['startDate']) {
        return -1;
    } else if ($line1['startDate'] == $line1['startDate']) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

$lines = explode("\n", $_POST['changeQueue']);
$parsedLines = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (!preg_match('/^\d{6}/', $line)) {
        continue;
    }
    $parsedLines[] = parseLine($line);
}
usort($parsedLines, 'compareLines');

var_dump($parsedLines);
```

Comment: This is working the way I am wanting it to.  My question now is would I be able to add more functions to be able to usort the same date different ways.

Comment: You can just change the functionality of the `compareLines` function. If you wanted it to sort it in descending order, just switch the `-1` and `1` returns.

Comment: What if I want to sort on multiple keys based upon specific key values?  And then put them in numeric order based upon dates.  Example I want to sort based upon key "taskType" where taskType='Approvals' and key "normal" where normal='Emergency'.

Comment: You just have to modify your `compareLines` method logic that determines how the lines are sorted. Compare whatever values you want, however you want to compare them. Just make sure you return a -1, 0, or 1.